# Que significa el LIFT?

Tags: r, ciencia-de-datos

Que significa el LIFT en data mining?

Busqué en internet pero no encuentro algo puntual en la web.

Agradeceria al que me pueda ayudar!

Saludos,
Nicolás.

Comment: Por la web hay bastante información. Para que se te pueda ayudar de mejor manera, lee un poco y lo que comprendas escribelo aquí para poder ampliar de mejor manera lo que hayas aprendido.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta no parece que entre dentro de la temática del sitio, no al menos como la has palnteado, podrías empezar por la [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining)). Saludos.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el centro de ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considero que el link, que te envío puede ayudarte de mucho. Por la web hay bastante información.

**Lift:** mide si la regla se debió al azar. Calcula el ratio entre la confianza de la regla y el consecuente de la regla o rhs.

http://apuntes-r.blogspot.com/2015/07/reglas-de-asociacion.html

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Hay que ayudar a los nuevos usuarios a realizar correctamente sus preguntas y si realizas una respuesta debes realizarla en base a [answer[.